# Trouble with one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, hibernate, one-to-many

Im trying to build a hotel application system and now i have laid out plans for the DB. My requirements are a guest searches for availability for a room. A room could either be king or queen, and smoking or non smoking. Also the guest enters the check in and out date. Based on the search the guest enters their info and reserve a room. Based on the reservation the service agent receives the receipt(reservationId). The service agent books the room upon receiving the reservationId. A guest can reserve several rooms per reservation. Now below is how my DB looks right now.

My **question** is since a guest can have several rooms per reservation how could i represent multiple rooms per reservation. Note: This will be done using hibernate. And below is my actual setup now for my DB please feel free to correct me if my approach is wrong: Below is a draft of how my db looks:

```
Reservation(resId(PK), checkIndate, checkOutDate, roomType, roomProperties, guestId(FK)).

Guest(guestId(PK), fname, lname, email, license, address_details).

Room(roomId(PK), roomNumber, roomProperties, roomType, price).

Booking(bookId(PK), resId(Fk), roomId)

RoomOccupied(bookId(PK and FK), roomId(PK and FK), flagChecKIfOccupied(default value is 0 if not occupied or 1 if occupied)

Payment(paymentId(PK), resId(FK), finalPayment)
```

Comment: What is your objection against having 2 reservation records for a reservation of 2 rooms?

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni because a guest can have a reservation for multiple room.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni won't each reservation be different or unique from the other. It seems i'm not understanding your question